# Cordova 1.9 and native controls plugin compatibility

Tags: javascript, cordova

I see native controls plugins worked fine on the cordova/phonegao before the version 1.6. But i cant get it work anymore with this code:

```
newLoc = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
// Initializating TabBar
nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls;
nativeControls.createTabBar();
// Back Button
nativeControls.createTabBarItem("page1", "Page 1", "www/images/pound.png", {
    "onSelect": function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page1", {
            transition: 'reverse slide'
        });
        nativeControls.setNavBarTitle("Page 1");
        nativeControls.selectTabBarItem("page1");
        selectedTabBarItem = "page1";
    }
});
// Home tab
nativeControls.createTabBarItem("page2", "Page 2", "www/images/pound.png", {
    "onSelect": function() {
        if (selectedTabBarItem == "page1") {
            $.mobile.changePage("#page2", {
                transition: 'slide'
            });
        } else {
            $.mobile.changePage("#page2", {
                transition: 'reverse slide'
            });
        }
        nativeControls.setNavBarTitle("Page 2");
        nativeControls.selectTabBarItem("page2");
        selectedTabBarItem = "page2";
    }
});
// About tab
nativeControls.createTabBarItem("page3", "Page 3", "www/images/question.png", {
    "onSelect": function() {
        $.mobile.changePage("#page3", {
            transition: 'slide'
        });
        nativeControls.setNavBarTitle("Page 3");
        nativeControls.selectTabBarItem("page3");
        selectedTabBarItem = "page3";
    }
});
// Compile the TabBar
nativeControls.showTabBar();
nativeControls.showTabBarItems("page1", "page2", "page3");
selectedTabBarItem = "page1";
nativeControls.selectTabBarItem("page1");
// Setup NavBar
nativeControls.createNavBar();
nativeControls.setNavBarTitle("Page 1");
nativeControls.setupLeftNavButton("?", "", "onLeftNavButton");
//nativeControls.hideLeftNavButton();
nativeControls.setupRightNavButton("About", "", "onRightNavButton");
nativeControls.showNavBar();
}
```

looking at the js file, it seems that now requires cordova.exec();

Anybody got it work?
And what's the difference between plugins iOS and iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the GitHub Project about this:
https://github.com/zSprawl/NativeControls

Just download project and open it in xcode 4.x
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, i saw that, but it's optimizzed for Cordova 1.7, anyway i make it work with TabBar and NavigatioBar. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error is that `window.plugins` is no longer supported in Cordova.

The solution:

Modify your calling script as follows (probably in your `onDeviceReady()` function - this may be inside your `controls.js` file if you use one:

```
// nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls; // get rid of (or comment out)
   nativeControls = new NativeControls(); // use this line instead
```

Fixed and working with Cordova 2.0 :-)

Hope that helps

Addendum: actually this will only get you part way - you will still need to edit the xCode files `NativeControls.m`.